# Problems saving file in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Trying to develop an android app over here that should save an audio recording and pipe it through some functions to get it to push eventually to a backend service.

Right now its failing at the first step. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help point out what this code is supposed to be doing and why it may be failing.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
      console.log(fileSystem + " gotFS function");
      fileSystem.root.getFile(audioData[0].name, null, 
                              gotFileEntry, console.log("GotFS failed"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

The problem was with the second parameter in

`fileSystem.root.getFile(audioData[0].name, null, gotFileEntry, console.log("GotFS failed"));`

It should be :

`fileSystem.root.getFile(audioData[0].name, {create : true}, gotFileEntry, fail);`